# Why can't I iterate over (Int, Int, Int) with Map?

Tags: scala

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use 'map' and stuff on Scala Tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339863/use-map-and-stuff-on-scala-tuples)

Why cannot I iterate over this construct (I am not sure how to call it, since Scala just calls it `(Int, Int, Int)`)?

```
val list = (1,2,3)
list.map{println _}
```

The code above produces the following error:

> <console>:9: error: value map is not a member of (Int, Int, Int)
>   (1,2,3).map{println _}

Answer (score 5):

You can use `.productIterator` or `.productElements` for such things:

```
t.productElements.toList.map(println)
```

I've used toList to strict operation, cause productIterator returns Iterator which is lazy.

Tip: it is recommended to use `.foreach` for functions without result (those that produce side effects, just like println do)

```
t.productElements.toList.foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 4):

I got it.

It's called a "tuple", and it's already answered here.

[Use 'map' and stuff on Scala Tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339863/use-map-and-stuff-on-scala-tuples)

Comment: I added an answer to that question with a pointer to [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) which might be useful.

Answer (score 3):

Based on on the name of your value `list`, it seems like you meant to use a [List](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html) instead of a [Tuple](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Tuple2.html). Try this to create a `List` which defines `map`:

```
List(1,2,3).map{println _}
```

Comment: could you please define the minus?

Comment: That was me, sorry about late reasoning. I've downvoted, cause *use another type/collection* is not appropriate general solution, IMO. You may have a tuple given by API (e.g. returned from function), or some other restriction, when you just can't write List(...) instead of (...) )

Comment: +1 - It is very possible based on the value name `list` that in the original question, that a List was intended instead of a Tuple. Because of this, I feel that this is a valid answer. I edited to make it more clear what @ie is answering. The original question should be edited as well.