# How to change a list into a tuple in Scala?

Tags: list, scala, tuples

I have a sequence of operations, and the results are packed in a tuple to be given as a parameter to a method.

```
  val bs = byteArrayToBitSet(ba)
  val d = bs.filter(_ < dBits)
  val c = ...
  val b = ...
  val a = ...
  val r = (f(a), f(b), f(c), f(d)) // <--
  ((fn _).tupled)(r)
```

I'd like to modified the tuple generation code something like this:

```
  val r = List(a,b,c,d).map(f(_)) // returns List not tuple
```

I need to change the List into tuple in order to use `((fn _).tupled)(r)`. How can I do that?

I may come up with a new method that gets List as an input if there is no way to convert list into tuple, but I'd like to have the tuple solution if possible.

Answer (score 0):

A tuple's arity is known at compile time. A list's arity is only known at runtime. You will almost certainly not gain any profit from converting a list at runtime to a tuple.

In your example, `fn` supposedly has a fixed number of arguments, four. Using a list of size four doesn't help you here. You might look for a `map` method on tuples, but it doesn't exist:

```
(1, 2, 3, 4).map(_ + 1)   // method not found
```

See [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339863/use-map-and-stuff-on-scala-tuples) for an approach that uses the Shapeless library to provide such functionality.