# Map tuple to tuple in Scala

Tags: scala

I want to map a pair of options of String like the following

```
val pair: (Option[String], Option[String]) = (Some("a"), None)

val mapped: (String, String) = pair map {case (a:Option[String],b:Option[String]) => (a.getOrElse(""),b.getOrElse(""))}
```

but the output signature is different from what I expected

```
(Option[String],(String,String))
```

It seems that I'm missing something here... maybe scalaz or shapeless allows for such functionality of mapping tuples?

Comment: I can not compile your code.

Comment: As it stands, this does not compile for me (and I would not expect it to - the type `Pair` / `Tuple2` doesn't have a `map` method). Is there a `List` or `Map` involved here that you have tried to take out to simplify the question?

Comment: [Apparently shapeless does support `Tuple#map`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10487475/2823715)

Comment: @rahilb it was added at 2.0 version as mentioned in Miles's answer

Answer (score 7):

Simple change from `map` to `match` you'll get expected types.

```
scala>   val pair: (Option[String], Option[String]) = (Some("a"), None)
pair: (Option[String], Option[String]) = (Some(a),None)

scala>

scala>   val mapped: (String, String) = pair match {case (a:Option[String],b:Option[String]) => (a.getOrElse(""),b.getOrElse(""))}
mapped: (String, String) = (a,"")

scala>

scala>   mapped
res8: (String, String) = (a,"")
```

Comment: it seems i got 'map' from scalaz imported, which is probably misled me)

Comment: @stanislav.chetvertkov `map` in scalaz treats `Tuple2` as monad. During `map` it will change only second part as defined [here](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/c847654dcf75c748eacbaf246511bbd938b8631f/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/std/Tuple.scala#L941)

Answer (score 0):

In case if you specifically want to do things like that with [**shapeless**](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless), you should make some preparations.

First tell your compiler what you want to use in case of `None`:

```
class Default[T](val value: T)

implicit object defaultString extends Default[String]("")
```

Now create your function to `map`:

```
import shapeless._

object extract extends Poly1 {
  implicit def withDefault[T](implicit default: Default[T]) =
    at[Option[T]](_ getOrElse default.value)
}
```

Now use [shapeless extension for tuples](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#hlist-style-operations-on-standard-scala-tuples):

```
import syntax.std.tuple._

pair.map(extract) // res0: (String, String) = (a,)
```